android gridView images duplicated on scroll
Iam facing a Problem that my GridView duplicate the images after I scroll to the 4th row or longer than 2 seconds.
I load items using Adapter into the GridView. An Item consists of a school name, school logo and school background image. i load images with "Glide" without resizing, crop or anything else.
Please see the attached image to follow my explanation.
Gridview Image
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final adptrSchoolsGetter adptrSchoolsGetter4 = adptrSchoolsGetter2[position];

        ViewHolder viewHolder;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.adptr_schools_list, parent, false);

            final TextView lblSchoolIDTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblSchoolID);
            final TextView lblSchoolNameTextView = (TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblSchoolName);
            final CircleImageView imgSchoolLogo= (CircleImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imgSchoolLogo);
            final View imgSchoolBackground= (View) convertView.findViewById(R.id.pnlSchoolBackground);

            viewHolder = new adptrSchoolsCustom.ViewHolder( lblSchoolIDTextView ,lblSchoolNameTextView  , imgSchoolLogo, imgSchoolBackground);;
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (adptrSchoolsCustom.ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewHolder.lblSchoolIDTextView.setText(String.valueOf(adptrSchoolsGetter4.getSchoolID()));
        viewHolder.lblSchoolNameTextView.setText(adptrSchoolsGetter4.getSchoolNameEN());
        
        Glide
                .with(mContext)
                .load(adptrSchoolsGetter4.getSchoolAvaterURL() + "-logo.png")
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.loading)
                .error(R.drawable.smart_school_logo)
                .transition(DrawableTransitionOptions.withCrossFade())
                .into(viewHolder.imgSchoolLogo);
         Glide.with(mContext)
                .load(adptrSchoolsGetter4.getSchoolAvaterURL() + "-background.jpg")
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.DATA)
                 .into(new SimpleTarget<Drawable>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResourceReady(@NonNull Drawable resource, @Nullable Transition<? super Drawable> transition) {
                        viewHolder.imgSchoolBackground.setBackground(resource);
                    }
                });
        return convertView;
    }

    public class ViewHolder {
        private final TextView lblSchoolIDTextView ,lblSchoolNameTextView  ;
        CircleImageView imgSchoolLogo ;
        View imgSchoolBackground;
        public ViewHolder(TextView lblSchoolIDTextView,TextView lblSchoolNameTextView, CircleImageView imgSchoolLogo,View imgSchoolBackground) {
            this.lblSchoolIDTextView = lblSchoolIDTextView;
            this.lblSchoolNameTextView = lblSchoolNameTextView;
            this.imgSchoolLogo = imgSchoolLogo;
            this.imgSchoolBackground=imgSchoolBackground;
        }
    }

i need to fix this issue
